# How to change the url of my website to a seo friendly one?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I own this website:  http://www.finalyearondesk.com . 
I want to change the url like :
    http://www.finalyearondesk.com/index.php?idname=how-to-recover-ubuntu-after-it-is-crashed
to something like this:
    *finalyearondesk.com/posts/how-to-recover-ubuntu-after-it-is-crashed*
using .htaccess. I don't have any knowledge of .htaccess, and I tried a lot of tutorials available online but all effort goes to vain.
So tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)$ /index.php?idname=$1 [L]
```

If it doesn't work, check that the file begins with a dot, that your hoster allows you to use .htaccess files or try to add `Options +FollowSymLinks`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)$ /index.php?idname=$1 [L]
```